# How to insert records like name, contact, image in SQLite?

Tags: android, sqlite

```
public class MyDataBase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public MyDataBase(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table tableregimage(int userid number autoincrement,username text,useraddress text,usercontact text,image blob);");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of asking directly ,do some research . google it. try something and if  you get any trouble ask here.

Comment: @Aman Kumar : Saving an image in database is not a great idea buddy :) Try saving it in a folder either in internal or external memory depending on your app requirement and then save the relative path to that folder in your data base :)

Answer (score 1):

This Method help you insert record:

```
 void addContact(String Name,String Contact,String Image) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, Name ); 
    values.put(KEY_CONTACT, Contact);
    values.put(KEY_IMAGE, Image)

    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_CName, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
}
```